# In Typed.JS and React can you hide the cursor until the string starts typing?

Tags: reactjs, typed.js

I have a string being animated in React using Typed.Js, but it starts on a delay of 3.5 seconds.  For those 3.5 seconds, the cursor is just sitting there, not doing anything. Is there a way to make it so that the cursor is not visible until the string starts typing? I already have it set to remove the cursor when the string is done being typed.

`<h1 className="sub-opening"><Typed strings={["Full Stack Web Developer"]} startDelay={3500} typeSpeed={40} onComplete={(self) => self.cursor.remove()} /></h1>`

Answer (score 1):

To hide the cursor, before your declaration of strings, simply type

```
...
showCursor: false
...
```